# Unable to load DLL 'mozglue': Error in Geckofx 45.0.1

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

i am trying to setup a windows application which embeds Geckofx Web Browser. version 45.0.1 
I have successfully embedded browser in windows form but when i run application an expection is thrown saying

```
   Unable to load DLL 'mozglue':
```

Location targeted in xpcom.initialize contains mozglue.dll file.  But still there is an error.

Any solution to this ?? how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using the GitHub or the nuget version?

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is caused by missing DLLs that are required to load `mozglue`.

1. Check whether the Firefox folder was copied to the output folder and contains these three files: `D3DCompiler_43.dll`, `msvcp120.dll`, and `msvcr120.dll`.

   If not, a [vcredist](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/3179560/update-for-visual-c-2013-and-visual-c-redistributable-package) that matches your architecture/build target might be required on some machines.
2. On this related [issue](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues/194/unable-to-load-dll-mozglue) on GeckoFX's bitbucket tracker is also mentioned to check whether the file `omni.ja` is in the Firefox folder after deployment.

   You need to get `omni.ja` there for `mozglue.dll` to run!
3. Furthermore, it may also be required to specify the location of the Firefox folder manually before initializing:

   ```
   System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location))
   Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox")
   ```

Comment: Thanks! For C# WPF I've used:             System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");

Answer (score 1):

in my case installing Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 fix the problem.
my case: run program on VPS Unable to load DLL 'mozglue'...
my program is 32bit and written with VS 2015, So i just download and install 32bit version of C++ 2015.

Answer (score -2):

Installed below redistributable to make it all work.

[image: See attachment for appwiz.cpl]